# Characterisation of second Sobolev space through Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, laplacian, poissons-equation

Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. We say that $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$ iff there exists $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that

\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega u \Delta \varphi \operatorname{dx} = \int_\Omega f\varphi \operatorname{dx} \quad (\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)).
\end{equation}

In this case we write $\Delta u =f$. My question is whether $H^2(\Omega)= \{u \in H^1(\Omega) : \Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)\}$? Maybe there are conditions on $\Omega$ such that the equality holds?

Comment: $H^2 \subset H^1$ should be clear through the definition.

Comment: It was a mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Some additional assumptions on $\Omega$ and $u$ are needed. A typical result would be (section 6.3.2 in *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans): if $\partial \Omega$ is $C^2$ smooth, $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ (notice the zero boundary condition), and $\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$, then $u\in H^2(\Omega)$. A more general form, Theorem 8.12 in *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations* by Gilbarg and Trudinger, does not require zero boundary condition but makes the assumption that the boundary trace of $u$ is compatible with some $H^2(\Omega)$ function, which is essentially the same thing (just subtract that function).

I'll give some reasons for why we need such assumptions

#### Geometry of $\Omega$

In $\mathbb R^2$ consider $u(x_1,x_2)=\log(x_1^2+x_2^2)$. This is a harmonic function on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$, so $\Delta f = 0$. Its gradient satisfies $\|\nabla u(x)\| \sim \|x\|^{-1}$ and the Hessian matrix is of size $\|x\|^{-2}$. Neither is square integrable in a neighborhood of $0$, but the Hessian is "more nonintegrable". So, it $\Omega$ has an outward cusp touching $0$, say $\Omega = \{x : 0\le x_2\le x_1^2 \le 1 \}$, then 
$$
\int_\Omega \|\nabla u\|^2 \approx \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^2}t^2\,dt <\infty
$$ 
but 
$$
\int_\Omega \|D^2 u\|^2 \approx \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^4}t^2\,dt  = \infty
$$

#### Boundary conditions

Let $\Omega$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$. Any integrable function on $\partial \Omega$ extends to a harmonic function on $\Omega$. A discontinuity, or some other poor behavior on the boundary is reflected in the growth of derivatives toward that point. Derivatives of higher order are affected more strongly, so it is possible to make the boundary values bad enough so that $u\notin H^2(\Omega)$ yet not bad enough to lose $u\in H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and the references! The Theorem 8.12 is very close to what I was looking for :). Do you know if there is a similar Theorem for the weak normal derivative instead of the trace? So if the weak normal derivative of u on the boundary is compatible with some $H^2(\Omega)$ function, then $u\in H^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: So, by subtracting off that $H^2$ functions we get the homogeneous Neumann problem $\partial u/\partial n=0$. This is discussed [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/37924) and it seems that the book by P. Grisvard, "Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains", is a good source for such results. I just searched for "sobolev regularity poisson equation neumann problem"...